# Customer email provider checking email activation link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

So this happen to me with Hotmail anti-spam system checking the email link causing that if I send and activation email link to the newly registered user, then then activation is not going to be performed by the user, what can I do to prevent this?

I am new to Laravel 5.4 and in my previous apps I just ask the client for the password to confirm their account after they follow the activation link.

Comment: Does hotmail actually send the email? or is it placed into the spam folder of the recipient?

Comment: How are you sending the email? What headers do you pass? It may be better to use something like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) or [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/).

Comment: I send the email using sendmail and hotmail does deliver the email but their bot visits the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various things that can cause our emails to go into someone's spambox. Try reading https://serverfault.com/q/419407 or https://serverfault.com/q/48428